# how should batch size be customised?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am running a VAE in Keras. the model compiles, and its summary is :
[image]

however, when I try to train the model I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 16 for '{{node vae_mlp/tf_op_layer_AddV2_14/AddV2_14}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT, _cloned=true](vae_mlp/tf_op_layer_Mul_10/Mul_10, vae_mlp/tf_op_layer_Mul_11/Mul_11)' with input shapes: [16,32,32], [16].
```

The 16 is the batch size. I know because if I change to any number greater than 1, I get the same error that mentions the batch size (and it works for a batch size of 1). I suspect that the problem is that stimuli have 3 channels and that for some reason, it treats it as if it is greyscaled. But I am not sure.
I am attaching the full code as well:

```
"""### VAE Cifar 10"""

from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras import regularizers

from keras.datasets import cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], x_train.shape[3])
original_dim=x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2]
latent_dim = 12

import keras

#encoder architecture
encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

cx=layers.Conv2D(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',
                padding='same')(encoder_input)
cx=layers.Conv2D(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',
                input_shape=(32, 32, 3),padding='same')(cx)

cx=layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)(cx)
cx=layers.Dropout(0.2)(cx)

cx=layers.Conv2D(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',padding='same')(cx)
cx=layers.Conv2D(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',padding='same')(cx)


cx=layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)(cx)
cx=layers.Dropout(0.2)(cx)

cx=layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',padding='same')(cx)
cx=layers.Conv2D(filters=128,
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',padding='same')(cx)

cx=layers.MaxPool2D(2,2)(cx)
cx=layers.Dropout(0.2)(cx)

x=layers.Flatten()(cx)

z_mean=layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu', name = 'z_mean')(x) #I removed the softmax layer
z_log_sigma=layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu',name = 'z_sd' )(x)

from keras import backend as K #what is that...

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim),
                              mean=0., stddev=0.1)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon

z = layers.Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])

# Create encoder
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_input, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name='encoder')

encoder.summary()

# Get Conv2D shape for Conv2DTranspose operation in decoder
conv_shape = K.int_shape(cx)

# Create decoder
#look at : https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2019/12/30/how-to-create-a-variational-autoencoder-with-keras/

from keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose, Reshape

latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim, ), name='z_sampling') #shape=(latent_dim,) or shape=late_dim?

d0 = layers.Dense(conv_shape[1] * conv_shape[2] * conv_shape[3], activation='relu')(latent_inputs)

d05     = Reshape((conv_shape[1], conv_shape[2], conv_shape[3]))(d0)

d1=layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128,
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                strides=2,
                activation='relu',padding='same')(d05)#(latent_inputs)
d2=layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128,
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                strides=2,
                activation='relu',padding='same')(d1)

d3=layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                strides=2,
                activation='relu',padding='same')(d2)

d4=layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',padding='same')(d3)

d5=layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',
                padding='same')(d4)

d6=layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, 
                kernel_size=(3, 3),
                activation='relu',
                input_shape=input_shape,padding='same')(d5)

outputs = layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(d6) #Dense(128, activation='relu')

from keras import Model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()

# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(encoder_input)[2]) 
vae = keras.Model(encoder_input, outputs, name='vae_mlp')

vae.summary()



#loss
reconstruction_loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(encoder_input, outputs)
reconstruction_loss *= original_dim
kl_loss = 1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma)
kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')

#batch size = 1 doens't break after one epoch
print('you use x_train_t')
vae.fit(x_train, x_train,
        epochs=20,
        batch_size=16,
        validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that required to solve the issue:
First, the way to attach the loss function to the model should be by:

```
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=val_loss_func)
```

Second, before training one should run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

I am not sure what this does..